# Prolog functor , swi-prolog

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

Check if the predicate functor(Term, F, A) succeeds if Term has functor F and arity A by defining a functor

The code I've tried is

likes(Mary,pizza)

Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described at https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=functor/3

```
?- functor(likes('Mary', pizza), Name, Arity).
Name = likes,
Arity = 2.

?- functor(Term, likes, 2).
Term = likes(_,_).
```

Beware: Variables start with a capital letter, so the value Mary is `'Mary'`, because Mary is instead a reference to a variable.